# SQL Insert duplicate key update is not working

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have create a sql using insert on duplicate key update. i wonder why it not able to insert into or update the data and keeping telling me error.

here below is my sample sql

```
Insert Into tbAdminContact(ContactID,EmpID,Contact,SpeedDial,company,CreatedBy,CreatedDate ) 
    Values( @Contactid,@EmpID,@Contact,@SpeedDial,@company,@createdby,convert(datetime,@createddate,103)) 
    On Duplicate key Update Contact=values(@Contact), SpeedDial=values(@SpeedDial), UpdatedBy=values(@UpdatedBy), UpdatedDate=values(convert(datetime,@UpdatedDate,103))
```

Error code

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'On'.

Comment: Certainly you can't simply use `ON` clause with `INSERT`. Probably you want to use `SELECT` with `JOIN` and put all its results with `INSERT`.

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is a MySQL feature.  If you are using SQL Server (a different database entirely), it wont work

Comment: is there any other query that able to work similar with 'on duplicate key update' ?

Comment: It depends what it does. Maybe you want to use `MERGE` instead of `INSERT` which allows you to update or insert.

Comment: What column is the key? Contactid or empid? If this is sql you can use a try catch and handle the problem... built in functions such as error number or errormessage will be what you want. As @Nick.McDermaid mention you can use merge, but this is no longer supported, introduced in 2008. Another option is you an use where not exist...

Comment: @Codexer AFAIK `merge` is still supported. Overused perhaps :) Can you reference something indicating that it isn't supported?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this

```
Update tbAdminContact set Contact=values(@Contact), SpeedDial=values(@SpeedDial), UpdatedBy=values(@UpdatedBy), UpdatedDate=values(convert(datetime,@UpdatedDate,103))
where ContactID=@Contactid

IF @@ROWCOUNT=0

Insert Into tbAdminContact(ContactID,EmpID,Contact,SpeedDial,company,CreatedBy,CreatedDate ) 
    Values( @Contactid,@EmpID,@Contact,@SpeedDial,@company,@createdby,convert(datetime,@createddate,103))
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if that is T-SQL (SQL Server) then it's not valid syntax.